# How do i get a random combination of elements from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I see many functions that give a single random element or all combinations of elements from an array but I am trying to find out something that returns a random combination each time.

```
ex) let array1 = ["mike", "ted","bill","mark"];

sample outputs would be like this 
output1 = mike, ted
output2= ted
output3 = mark,ted,bill,mike
output4 = mike, bill
```

it could be all of the elements or just a single random element.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the original array. Generate a random number n between 1 and the length of the copy, then loop n times to get a random index from the copied array n times. That's where you get your "name" values. Make sure you splice the copied array each time to avoid duplicates:

## Update:

I added a line to make a copy of the original array with `Array.slice()` before executing the rest of the code:

```js
let array1 = ["mike", "ted","bill","mark"];
let arrCopy = array1.slice()

let ranIdx
let resArr = []
let ranLen = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrCopy.length) + 1

for(i=0; i < ranLen; i++){
   ranIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrCopy.length)
   resArr.push(arrCopy.splice(ranIdx,1)[0])  
}

console.log(resArr)
```

Comment: By splicing, you destroy the original array. This might be a problem!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like This:

```js
  let array1 = ["mike", "ted","bill","mark"];

  function get_random_in_range(_min, _max) {
     _min = Math.ceil(_min);
     _max = Math.floor(_max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (_max - _min + 1)) + _min;
  }

  function get_randoms(_arr){
   var out = [];
   var count_of_rnd_out = get_random_in_range(0, _arr.length-1);
   for (var i = 0; i < count_of_rnd_out+1; i++) {
    var rnd_el_index = get_random_in_range(0, _arr.length-1);
    var rnd_el = _arr[rnd_el_index];
    while(out.indexOf(rnd_el) >= 0) {    /* for exclude duplicates */
      rnd_el_index = get_random_in_range(0, _arr.length-1);
      rnd_el = _arr[rnd_el_index];
       }
    out.push(rnd_el);
   }
   return out;
  }

  console.log(get_randoms(array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this package could be [useful](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics)

By using this code

```
cmb = Combinatorics.power(['a','b','c']);
```

It will generate all the combinations of the array. Then you could generate a number that is between 0 and the length of the array (inclusive) to select your random output.

Comment: By splicing, you destroy the original array.  This might be a problem!

Comment: @ScottSauyet ?? This is not splicing anything

Comment: Sorry, somehow added this to the wrong answer... odd.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this atop a function that partially shuffles an array, returning a randomized choice of the first `n` elements from it.  Furthermore, I would randomly choose the number of elements to pick.  We could do it with boundaries ("pick from 1 to 3 elements from the list") or without ("pick from 1 to list.length elements").

Both of those options are shown here, with `anyRandomSubset` built atop `randomSubset`, which takes the boundaries.  We could easily skip the intermediary if the boundaries are not needed.

Here is an implementation of this:

```js
const {random, floor} = Math

const excluding = (i) => (xs) => 
  [... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)]

const partialShuffle = (n) => (xs, i = floor(random () * xs .length)) =>
  n <= 0 || n > xs .length || xs .length == 0
    ? []
    : [xs[i], ... partialShuffle (n - 1) (excluding (i) (xs))]

const randomSubset = (lo, hi) => (xs) =>
  partialShuffle (floor (random () * (hi - lo + 1) + lo)) (xs)

const anyRandomSubset = (xs) => 
  randomSubset (1, xs .length) (xs)

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console .log (anyRandomSubset (["mike", "ted","bill","mark"]))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The `partialShuffle` is a variant of this complete shuffle function:

```
const shuffle = (xs, i = floor(random () * xs.length)) =>
  xs.length == 0
    ? []
    : [xs[i], ... shuffle (excluding (i) (xs))]
```

This is a recursive formulation of the most common true shuffle of an array,  the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  This recursive version would run into recursion-depth problems if we used it for a long array (or for a large `n` in our partial version above.)  But it's probably fine for smallish arrays.

Note that `partialShuffle` and its helper function `excluding` are both useful utility functions.  Only `randomSubset` and `anyRandomSubset` are specific to this problem.